# Post request to create new custom users in Django

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a model where I extend the User model:

```
class ReaderUser(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        email = models.EmailField()                                                                     

        def __unicode__(self):                                                                          
          return self.user.first_name + ',' + str(self.email)
```

I create also resources for my tastypie API:

```
class CreateReaderUserResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.OneToOneField('UserResource', 'user', full=False)                                 

    class Meta:
        allowed_methods = ['post']                                                                  
        always_return_data = True
        authentication = Authentication()                                                           
        authorization = Authorization()                                                             
        queryset = ReaderUser.objects.all()                                                         
        resource_name = 'newuser'


class ReaderUserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = ReaderUser.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get, put, patch']
        resource_name = 'ruser'                                                                     


class UserResource(ModelResource):                                                                  
    raw_password = fields.CharField(attribute=None, readonly=True, null=True,                       
                                      blank=True)                                                     

    class Meta:
        authentication = MultiAuthentication(
            BasicAuthentication(),
            ApiKeyAuthentication())
        authorization = Authorization()

        allowed_methods = ['get', 'patch', 'put']
        always_return_data = True
        queryset = User.objects.all()
```

When I try to create a new user by creatin a POST request, using curl, I got the following:

```
 ->curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"email": "test@test.com", "password": "groscaca"}' http://localhost:8000/api/newuser/
HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND
Date: Tue, 03 Sep 2013 21:17:28 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.1
Content-Type: application/json

\"/Users/jrm/Documents/Perso/simplereader/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py\", line 389, in __get__\n    
raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist\n\nDoesNotExist\n"}
```

What am I doing wrong? I try to have a setup as simple as possible. I know the issue is coming from the OneToOneField keyword, but I don't know how to fix. I checked many different solutions and didn't find any working for me.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data needs to contain the `User` you'd like to attach your `ReaderUser` to.

If I remember correctly, you should submit the full object representation of the user, as would be returned if you did e.g.: `curl http://localhost:8000/api/user/1`

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"email": "test@test.com", "password": "", "user": {"blah"}}' http://localhost:8000/api/newuser
```

---

If you don't have any `User` though, you'll need to create one first. You can of course do this with another API call.

Comment: Ok but if I wanna create a reader user, the user assiocated to it is not existing yet, what am I supposed to give as a user then?

Comment: @JeremyD You're supposed to create the user first, or alter you model definition. As of now, your model definition requires that a `ReaderUser` be attached to a `User`: `user = models.OneToOneField(User)`

Comment: So, if I understand well, I can find a way to create the User just before the ReaderUser in a single call?

Comment: You'll need to create the user first, yes, you could this using an API call, before creating the `ReaderUser`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. One more thing, should I just create a totally separate user, not extending the User model, to have only one call to do? (Architectural question)

Comment: @JeremyD That depends on your application. That might be simpler, yes. You may also want to have a look at Django's new [Custom User Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) features.

Answer (score 0):

I finally decide to create my own user, without relying on the User model.
I have optimal control on my model which makes me feel more confident about what I do.

Nevertheless Thomas' solution is totally correct. I just didn't want to have to do two POST request to create one tuple in my database.